# check what type of pointer void* is pointing to in C

Tags: c, pointers

In my C program I am using void* pointers. Is there anyway to check in an if statement if the void* pointer is pointing to an int* or a char*?

Comment: in objective-c they handled this by having the first member be a pointer to isa... as in if this object->isa == someObject->isa then they are the same typea

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nope. There is no run-time type information in C.  A `void*` is just an address. That's it. It's completely up to the programmer to know / keep track of what information a `void*` points to.

With more information about how/why you're using `void*`, a workaround could possibly be suggested.